# Call a script in SharePoint PowerShell post-deployment command line with array in parameters

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I try to call on post-deployment action a powerShell script with an array parameter, but without success.

Here is the script:

```
param(
        [string[]]$ModelNameList = "DefaultModelName"
    )

  Write-Host "Number of Models is: $($ModelNameList.Count)"
```

and this is the post-deployment command line:

```
%windir%\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell -File "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\Post_Deployment\Script.Post-Deployment.ps1"  -ModelNameList "m2","m1"
```

> Result : Number of Models is: 1

Running the same script in SharePoint2010 Management Shell return the correct result.

> Result : Number of Models is: 2

Comment: try passing just `"m2,m1"`...

Comment: @C.B. Doesn't help. CMD passes it as a single string argument either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CMD` doesn't know anything about PowerShell arrays, so it passes `"m2","m1"` into the powershell script as a single string. You can see that when you add

```
Write-Host $ModelNameList[0]
Write-Host $ModelNameList[0].GetType()
```

to your PowerShell script. I think you have to split the argument inside your script:

```
if ($ModelNameList[0] -match ',') {
  $ModelNameList = $ModelNameList[0].Split(',')
}
```